# Does Jooq support Sql Server 2014 and 2017?

Tags: java, sql-server, jooq

I am developing my application in Sql Server 2014 and will upgrade to Sql Server 2017 when it is released. According, to Jooq they support up to Sql Server 2012. Can I still use Jooq with 2017? Will there be any features I am missing since the highest version Jooq supports is 2012?

Comment: Have you tried installing a preview version in a sandboxed environment to test your application? I know it's silly comment, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: *"According, to Jooq they support up to Sql Server 2012"* Where did you see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ supports [*"SQL Server 2008 and later"*](https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing#databases). All popular SQL databases are very backwards compatible, so jOOQ officially supports all new versions of a specific database.

#### SQL dialect configurations

This is not to be confused with the available [`SQLDialect`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html) versions, which (as of jOOQ 3.9) list:

- [`SQLSERVER`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER) - The dialect family, which corresponds to the latest currently available dialect configuration (2014 in jOOQ 3.9)
- [`SQLSERVER2008`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER2008)
- [`SQLSERVER2012`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER2012)
- [`SQLSERVER2014`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER2014)

jOOQ 3.10 will also add a dialect configuration for:

- [`SQLSERVER2016`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6239)

jOOQ 3.11 will add a configuration for:

- [`SQLSERVER2017`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6328)

Even if SQL Server 2017 cannot be configured in jOOQ 3.9, yet, this doesn't mean it won't be supported. You can choose any of the above SQL dialect configurations. They will all work on SQL Server 2017.

The main reasons for adding new dialect version configurations like the above are:

- To document that a specific function is only available from that version onwards (e.g. [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#listAgg-org.jooq.Field-) will be supported in SQL Server 2017)
- To switch to newer SQL constructs (e.g. `OFFSET .. FETCH` was supported natively in SQL Server 2012, jOOQ emulates it using `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Jooq is not free for SQLserver right ?. I want to use  simple jooq aggregation with HikariCP connection pool with multiple sql databses. 
shall i use basic features of MS SQL server from jooq (free edition) ??

Comment: @Slok: Please refer to the licensing documentation regarding the correct price plan to use with jOOQ and Microsoft SQL Server: https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing#databases